# How to make a view pointing to dynamically created database

Tags: database, stored-procedures, view, teradata, informatica

I would like to create a view upon a database which changes on time .
For Example: initially, a view layer is to be created for the database B1_2016 in the next refresh, a new database is created and named as B2_2016. So the view layer is to be pointed to B2_2016. In this way, the view layer should point to the newest database created.How can this be achieved in Teradata

Comment: The basic recommendation in Teradata is access via a 1:1-view on each base table. It's a simple process to recreate those views with a new database name.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. These views should be updated through a stored procedure having the database name dynamic. I mean there should be no manual intervention. I would need an approach in such a way that the procedure finds the latest database and eventually the views layer should be pointed to the same

Comment: "*no manual intervention*": you need to run/schedule the SP, so you will know the new DB name (or you must define a rule how to find it).

Answer (score 0):

That simply isn't how SQL works.

View definitions are part of a schema, and as such themselves part of a database.  They cannot ever depend on "variables" that make the view definition itself dependent upon "different databases at different times".

Allowing such stuff is a near guarantee to make the system they are part of worse than just brittle.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there a way to do this approach in Teradata